# Ruby - convert single backslash unicode to double backslash

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

I have a string that looks something like `'\\u001E\\u001Csome_text\u001F'` - where the first two characters are escaped with two backslashes and the last one only has one backslash.

I want to convert that string so that all the unicode literals have two backslashes in them, so the output would look like `'\\u001E\\u001Csome_text\\u001F'`.  What ways could I go about doing this?

Comment: If there's something wrong with my question (as indicated by the downvotes), what can I do to make the question better?

Comment: So you want to convert every single blackslash to double backslash? And if there's more than 3 or more backslashes?

Comment: I'd like to only convert the unicode characters.  So any instance of `\uxxxx` should be converted to `\\uxxxx`.  Things like `\"` should be left alone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Your question is premature. Instead of asking us all the ways you can do something, you need to try, then, when you have a problem, show us the minimum code demonstrating the problem you ran into. Currently your question is too broad.

Comment: If you use single quotes you needn't worry about escapes.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to find instances of '\u' not preceded by a '\' character, then a negative lookbehind should suit the need to match:

```
(?<!\\)\\u
```

If you want to match the whole character, then you can also use a positive lookahead to verify the following characters:

```
(?<!\\)\\u(?=[0-9A-Z]{4})
```

Both of these will return the instances of '\u', which you can replace with '\\u'